# How to express the matrix formulation of taking a part of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $X$ with size $N$ x $N$, I need to write the small matrices  $x$ and $T$ taken from $X$. $x$ takes  $1: 4: N$ elements from the matrix $X$  and also from each columns the same elements, $1:4:N$ , it means that $x$ = $X_{1:4:N, 1:4:N}$.  On the other hand $T$ columns should contains  $X_{1:4:N}$ and its row $X_{1:N} $ - $X_{1:4:N}$  it means in its rows, I need to discard values taken for the matrix $x$.
How can I formulate that mathematically?

Comment: What do you mean by $1:4:N$? Is that Python notation? Matlab notation?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I mean the indices of taken elements,  for example if the length of the vector $8$, so it's $1:4:N$ elements are the elements located at $[1, 5]$